# Making certain words in an NSString bold and clickable like tags

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, ios8

I need to make certain words in a NSString be clickable and a different font style like a tag would.

I have a code like so:

```
NSString *str = @"This is my string and it is #cool and #fun.  Please click on the tags.";
```

So the above word #cool and #fun would become buttons to a uibutton action.  In the function I would pass cool or fun to a new UIViewController.

Thanks!

Comment: Use this https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code snippet

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Google"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.google.com" range: NSMakeRange(0,str.length)];
[str addAttribute:kCTFontAttributeName value: boldFontName range: NSMakeRange(0,str.length)];
yourTextField.attributedText = str;
```

---

*Edit*

The closest thing to implementing methods similar to `UIButton` action for a string like this would be to first find the rect of the selected range in a `UITextView` using the `firstRectForRange:` method, and then overlaying an actual invisible `UIButton` with the connected action.

Check out [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483697/add-tap-event-to-ios-nsmutableattributedstring)

Comment: Indeed. Let me search for a bit and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

This would need to be an NSAttributedString, not an NSString. An NSAttributedString lets you apply a style run to just one part of the text. And such a style run can include a clickable link.

You can change the font to a bold variant with the `NSFontAttributeName` attribute, and you can add the link with the `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute.

Comment: I've told you exactly what you need to know. You should write your own code. Stack Overflow is not about getting others to think for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer the below sample code:-

```
NSString *str = @"This is my string and it is #cool and #fun.  Please click on the tags.";
NSMutableAttributedString *yourAtt=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];
for (NSString *word in [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "])
{
    if ([word isEqualToString:@"#cool"] || [word isEqualToString:@"#fun."])
    {
     [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString  alloc]initWithString:word attributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName:@"http://www.google.com"}]];
    }
    else
    {
     [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString  alloc]initWithString:word attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]}]];
    }
    [yourAtt appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@" "]];
}
self.yourAttStr=yourAtt;
```

Output is two word #cool and #fun is clickable now and remaining fonts are in bold:-
[image]

Comment: Not what I wanted. Edited my post.

Comment: Ok so what is your requirement??

Comment: I edited my post. Read above.

Comment: Chris, have updated the answer and let me know if this helps??

Comment: How do you make the #fun or #cool a UIButton or add a tap gesture to another UIViewController?

Comment: good work @HussainShabbir