# Text with multiple buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsattributedstring

Inside a `tableview cell` i want to display text like
`Marc is now friends with Chris`.
I want to use both `Marc` and `Chris` as buttons to navigate to their profile.

My first idea was to use `NSAttributedString` but i do not know if i can use the text as different buttons.
I´m not a complete newbie so navigation works, display of cells works everything works.
I am not asking for working code but i have no idea how to solve this...
Maybe someone could tell me wich class could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UITextView` with `NSAttributedString` (and `NSLinkAttributeName`) should do the trick.

Comment: You could search for the rect that contains that text within the UITextView.  For example, Marc and Chris are each their own rect that can be a clickable NSLinkAttributeName within your NSAttributedString, heres a helpful link with some code examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220986/making-certain-words-in-an-nsstring-bold-and-clickable-like-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TTTAttributedLabel` from github. Provides this capability out of the box using various attributes on `NSAttributedString`